# Linq, Joining a list to last item in another list

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a list of Users and another list of users activities.
I want to get list of users including user last activity.
I tried this:

```
var usersActivity = 
  from user in Users
  join activity in Activities on user.Id equals activity.UserId
  group activity by activity.UserId into UserActivities
  select new {
     activity=UserActivities.OrderByDescending(g=>g.DateTime).First(),
     user=user
  }
```

But it does not works. it says: The name 'user' does not exist in the current context

Am I wrong in joining or grouping?

Comment: "It does not work": what happens? Do you get an empty list, an exception, the wrong output???

Comment: I updated my code with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping by user instead of user ID:

```
var usersActivity =
    from user in Users
    join activity in Activities on user.Id equals activity.UserId
    group activity by user into UserActivities
    select new
    {
        activity = UserActivities.OrderByDescending(g => g.DateTime).First(),
        user = UserActivities.Key
    };
```

Comment: this looks better. but what if I have another join clause in my query? for example: join profile in UserProfile on user.Id equals profile.UserId I tried your code but profile is not available in Key attribute

Comment: @desmati In that case you can use `group activity by new { user, profile } into UserActivities`, and then you can access user by `UserActivities.Key.user` and profile by `UserActivities.Key.profile`

Comment: I know this may be off this topic but how can I see the final sql generated by this linq query?

Comment: @desmati Check this [article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simpler approach:

```
var usersActivity = 
 from user in Users
 select new {
    activity=Activities.Where(a => a.UserId = user.Id).OrderByDescending(a => a.DataTime).FirstOrDefault(),
    user=user
 }
```

Comment: This works well. but I think it will do a query for each User. am i right?

Comment: I mean it will query activity table for every user.

Comment: It will generate a subquery, I guess. But the actual execution plan will depend on your database structure (not just tables, but indexes as well). In general SQL Server handles subqueries very efficiently. Don't optimize in advance, start with a working query and optimize it only if and when necessary.